# Lens distortion in compositor doesn’t support transparency

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

When rendering out an image and compositing it with lens distortion it puts on a black background which I don’t want because I want the image to have a transparent background. Is there a workaround this like a button or more compositing setup I need to do?

Comment: Did you try a *Set Alpha* node ? Quick testing on a duplicate of *Lens Distorsion* on alpha channel seems to work.

Comment: @Lutzi could you show me an example mode setup? I’m still new to the compositor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Lens distortion with alpha

*I can't guarantee it's the best way to achieve that. Visually, it seems to match the expected behavior. So I would say, it's good enough until you run into some issue.*

- Have *Render tab > Film > Transparent* enabled
- Repeat the *Lens Distortion* node for the alpha input
- *Set Alpha* will change the alpha channel to what is connected to it
- For ease of use, I would suggest connecting both parameters of *Lens Disortion* to a *Value* node. So that you tweak both nodes the same.

[image: Lens distortion with alpha channel]

If you're confused about the alpha channel, you can think of it as a black and white image representing the transparency. Black = 0 = transparent, white = 1 = non-transparent, with any shade of gray for semi-transparency. *Alpha channel* is an universal denomination (not Blender-only).

Comment: The only thing worth mentioning is maybe that the color of the _Dispersion_ is dependent on the colors of the image, object as well as background. So the resulting colors will always look as if you had a black background, unless you use an _Alpha Over_ node before plugging the image into the _Lens Distortion_ to give it a different tint.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's interesting. It should be visually correct if background gets the same Lens Distortion, right ? Or do you think Lens Distortion should be applied to subject and background altogether ?

Comment: I don't know what the OP needs the lens distortion with a transparent background for, if it should be composited over varying backgrounds, it would be incorrect dispersion if it would look the same on different backgrounds since it changes dependent on color. If  the OP knows which background to place it on before (and would apply the same dispersion to it), then having it on a transparent background is useless, the layers could be merged before using lens distortion. If it should later be composited over something (maybe in PS), then I thought it should be noted that the color might be wrong.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I would use a different software like PS but I just wannna just do it in like one software instead of many, making the most use of blender as possible because it can take up the ram on my pc and it’s also time consuming. The reason why I want lens dispersion with a transparent background is because I don’t usually like backgrounds mostly. I also need it to import to animation software and other stuff.

Comment: @Bludus Photoshop was just one possible example of many for not using the Blender _Compositor_. I just wanted to give you the additional information that dispersion is a color-relative effect and if it matters to you to have "correct" dispersion no matter what you put below it, this does not work with the transparent background. Just as info. If that's fine for you that's okay.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for the info anyways. I see lens dispersion as an effect rather than a correction considering the name ‘chromatic abberation’ which is what I’m mainly rooting for when I use lens dispersion. I know it’s used to emulate camera like effects but I use it as a more dramatic effect.

Comment: @Bludus Well, it is not a correction, it is more like intentional degradation in Blender. In real cameras lens distortion and chromatic aberration are flaws, imperfections of lenses, especially of lower quality which some photographers correct by removing it with software. So I would adding it in Blender rather not call a correction  But when you just it for some dramatic effect, I guess the colors should not matter - however, if you sometimes want to get a different color for the dispersion, you can do this by underlaying different backgrounds before the lens distortion.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks a lot though. I did do it and it worked how I wanted to expect it. I’m not a expert in effects but I am into effects a lot so I try my best to learn about it as much as possible 